# In telnet, what replaces <starts TLS negotiation>?

Tags: telnet, zoho

In the following document: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2487.txt

It stated that after running starttls client must do .

What should I write there in place of that?

My aim is to emulate a connection to Zoho's mail server: https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/zoho-smtp.html through command line.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are to use telnet for connecting to a mail server using tls then you will have to perform handshake operations manually. But these handshake operations can be automated by using an open source library which implements TLS. One such library is 'OpenSSL'. Below is the openssl command using which you can try connecting to the mail server using tls

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.zoho.com:587 -crlf -ign_eof
```